# How can I filter first_name then search the only first_name in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, search, pdo, filter

I have `select` and `textbox` input for my filter and search. When the user selects the First Name, the user can only search for the First Name. If the user searches for 'James' only the first name 'James' will appear in the table. How can I do that? Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my query.

```
  public function searchUserStatus($keyword) {
$sql = "SELECT tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.username, tbl_user.password, 
  tbl_user.first_name,tbl_user.last_name, tbl_user.is_employed, 
  tbl_barangay.barangay_name FROM tbl_user INNER JOIN tbl_barangay ON 
  tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_user.barangay_id WHERE 
  (tbl_user.first_name LIKE :keyword AND tbl_user.username LIKE :keyword 
  OR tbl_user.first_name LIKE :keyword OR tbl_user.last_name LIKE :keyword 
  OR tbl_user.barangay_name LIKE :keyword) OR (tbl_user.last_name LIKE 
  :keyword AND tbl_user.username LIKE :keyword OR tbl_user.first_name LIKE 
  :keyword OR tbl_user.last_name LIKE :keyword OR tbl_user.barangay_name 
  LIKE :keyword)";

  $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->execute([
":keyword" => '%' . $keyword . '%'
  ]);

  return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(searchUserStatus('James'))` give you? Seems like its your code that uses the data that causes the problem, not your SQL because it should return `['id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_employed', 'barangay_name']` columns

Comment: How can I fix it?  Can you help me? I want to select first the field name then I can only search the data depends on the field name I select.

Comment: Like I said, what does `var_dump(searchUserStatus('James'))` give you?

Comment: No data to show

Comment: Have you tried that on RAW sql? Have you get deserved answer?

Comment: not yet sir! I'm new in PHP

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do:

```
I have select and textbox input for my filter and search <-----
```

So you search by 2 parameters right? what does select has?
You can do this way to search different fields:

```
public function searchUserStatus($search, $keyword) {    
      $sql = "SELECT tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.username, tbl_user.password, 
      tbl_user.first_name,tbl_user.last_name, tbl_user.is_employed, 
      tbl_barangay.barangay_name FROM tbl_user INNER JOIN tbl_barangay ON 
      tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_user.barangay_id WHERE 
      (";
      switch($select){
          case 'first_name':
              $sql .= "tbl_user.first_name LIKE :keyword);";
              break;
          case 'last_name':
              $sql .= "tbl_user.last_name LIKE :keyword);";
              break;
          case 'username':
              $sql .= "tbl_user.username LIKE :keyword);";
              break;
          case 'barangay_name':
              $sql .= "tbl_user.barangay_name LIKE :keyword);";
              break;
      }

      ...
```